# Разбить float на 2 регистра (2 * 2 байта )

Tags: c, float

Необходимо одну переменную `float` (4 байта) разбить на 2 переменные `unsigned short` (2 байта) для хранение в 2 регистрах.

Хотел организовать это с использованием побитового сдвига, но с `float` такой номер не прокатывает.

Может есть какой алгоритм, как это правильнее всего можно сделать?

Задача: необходимо данные `float`, полученные путём измерений и вычислений, сохранять в двух переменных (старший и младший регистр) и передавать по modbus rtu.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Число_одинарной_точности

Comment: Какой собственно алгоритм вам нужен? Берете 4 байта, половину копируете в один регистр, половину — в другой.

Comment: Не понятно, какой у вас вообще язык. Если у вас есть возможность работь прямо с регистрами, то это скорее всего ассемблер. Тогда в чем вообще проблема?

Comment: @eanmos, язык Си, необходимо данные float, полученные путём измерений и вычислений, сохранять в 2х переменных (старший и младший регистр) и передавать по modbus rtu

Comment: @eanmos , "Какой собственно алгоритм вам нужен? Берете 4 байта, половину копируете в один регистр, половину — в другой."    я как-бы понимаю, чтобы получить 2 двухбайтные переменные нужно 4 байта разделять на 2 части по 2 байта, а вот как это правильно сделать - у меня вопрос!

Answer (score 3):

Единственный вариант, при котором мы можем знать о конкретной реализации чисел с плавающей точкой — это объявленный макрос `__STDC_IEC_559__`, который указывает на то, что `float` соответствует *IEC 60559 single-precision format*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef __STDC_IEC_559__
    #error "The implementation doesn't conform the IEC 60559 specification."
#endif

int main(void)
{
    const float number = 3.1415f;

    uint8_t bytes[4];
    memcpy(bytes, &number, sizeof number);

    uint16_t first, second;
    memcpy(&first, &bytes[0], 2);
    memcpy(&second, &bytes[2], 2);

    printf("%04x %04x\n", first, second);
}
```

*Не забудьте учесть [порядок байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) (англ. [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).*

Comment: второй вариант более понятен для меня, думаю, это решит мою проблему! спасибо!)

Comment: @Maks, я очень не советую его использовать.

Comment: в чём скрываются подводные камни?

Comment: @Maks, их довольно [много](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning). Как минимум в `asInteger.a` и `asInteger.b` может получится trap representation и работа с этими членами структурами приведет к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: я понял, спасибо за предупреждение

Comment: @AnT, здравствуйте. Мы ведь не можем быть уверены, что при копировании `byte[0-1]` в `first` и `byte[2-3]` в `second` в `first` и `second` не получится trap representation? Как тогда решить задачу наиболее грамотно?

Answer (score 1):

Структуру использовать опасно, компилятор может разместить данные не так как хотелось. Лучше использовать массив. Ключевое слово `volatile` - использовать обязательно. Иначе компилятор ничего правильно не сделает.

```
# include <stdio.h>

typedef  union {
    volatile  float    fl;
    volatile  unsigned short int reg  [ 2 ] ;
} uni_float ;

int main (){
  uni_float uf = { . fl = 3.1415926 } ;
  printf ( "%f = [ %u , %u ]\n" , uf . fl , uf . reg [ 1 ] , uf . reg [ 0 ] ) ; }
```

Comment: Попробую и ваш вариант испытать, спасибо!)